# How we can embed Equations of MS Word in DevExpress Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, cuteeditor

How we can embed Equations of MS Word in Dev Express Editor or Any Editor,
and I wanted same functionality as it works in MS Word inside the Editor such as Search and when copy pasted from MS Word to any of these editor it should not convert the MS Word Equation to Picture Format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into the WIRIS family of products. Formula editing is very complex and I seriously doubt any (X)HTML WYSIWIG editor will have that OOB: http://www.wiris.com/solutions/radeditor